# how can I plot calculated dynamic levels?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Where could be a mistake?

```
// Input für den iterativen prozentualen Schritt
PercentageStep_it = input(1, title="Percentage Step it")

// Berechnung des Preisbereichs
PriceRange = downfibo ? F_level_S - F_level_E : F_level_E - F_level_S

// Berechnung der iterativen Anzahl der zusätzlichen Ebenen
NumAdditionalLevels_it = downfibo ? int(PriceRange / (F_level_S * (1 + PercentageStep_it * 0.01) - F_level_S)) : int(PriceRange / (F_level_S - F_level_S * (1 - PercentageStep_it * 0.01)))

// Berechnung des tatsächlichen prozentualen Schritts
PercentageStep = PriceRange / math.ceil(NumAdditionalLevels_it) / F_level_S

// Berechnung der tatsächlichen Anzahl der zusätzlichen Ebenen
NumAdditionalLevels = downfibo ? int(PriceRange / (F_level_S * (1 + PercentageStep * 0.01) - F_level_S)) : int(PriceRange / (F_level_S - F_level_S * (1 - PercentageStep * 0.01)))

// Erstelle eine Liste der y-Werte für die zusätzlichen Levels
var float[] additional_levels = array.new_float(1)
for i = 1 to NumAdditionalLevels
    F_level_new = downfibo ? F_level_S * (1 - PercentageStep * 0.01 * i) : F_level_S * (1 + PercentageStep * 0.01 * i)
    array.push(additional_levels, F_level_new)

// Plot der dynamisch angepassten Prozentuale-Niveaus
for i = 0 to NumAdditionalLevels - 1
    plot(additional_levels[i], color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), linewidth=1, trackprice=true, show_last=1, title=f"Prozentuale Level {i+1}")
```

I can't find a solution to plot calculated levels.
I get everytime some mistake report.

Comment: You tell us. What is your problem or error? We need to see a [mcve], which includes any errors you are seeing.